# Take() works with chaining only?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a service function to query a SQL db like so:

```
public IQueryable<MyModel> getAll()
{
    IQueryable<MyModel> models = (from f in db.MyModel select f);

    return models;
}
```

When I implement it in my controller it works when I chain the Take():

```
var models = myModelEntities.getAll().Take(5); 
return View(models); // returns 5 rows to the view
```

But like this it doesn't:

```
var models = myModelEntities.getAll();
models.Take(5); 
return View(models); // returns thousands of rows to the view
```

Why is Take() ignored if it's not chained? I have Lazy Loading enabled on my model...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It *does* work, but you're not assigning the result of `Take()` to anything. `Take()` doesn't mutate the `models` variable, it returns the top 5 items in the enumerable.

The following **would** work:

```
var models = myModelEntities.getAll();
models = models.Take(5); 
return View(models); // returns five rows to the view
```

Comment: Hey no worries. Often I can't see the wood for the trees myself, easily overlooked when you're looking to hard. :)

Answer (score 2):

It's because `Take` doesn't mutate the current `IEnumerable`; it returns a new one.  This will work:

```
models = models.Take(5);
```

Answer (score 1):

You aren't assigning the result of the second Take() call to any variable.